# Fail to run flink-gelly-examples

Tags: apache-flink

I'm running Apache Flink 1.4.2 (Without bundled hadoop) on Mac, and I've managed to run the WordCount example. However, when I try to run the Gelly example following instructions in [Runnung Gelly Examples](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/libs/gelly/) , I stumble into the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.graph.generator.random.BlockInfo
```

May I know how can I fix it?

I first started the cluster by

```
./bin/start-cluster.sh 
Starting cluster.
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of jobmanager are already running on myhostname.
Starting jobmanager daemon on host myhostname.
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of taskmanager are already running on myhostname.
Starting taskmanager daemon on host myhostname.
```

Then in another terminal, I run

```
./bin/flink run examples/gelly/flink-gelly-examples_2.11-1.4.2.jar --algorithm GraphMetrics --order directed --input RMatGraph --type integer --scale 20 --simplify directed --output print
```

and the following errors

```
Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:6123
Using address localhost:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://localhost:8081
Starting execution of program
Submitting job with JobID: 099acb25fa34be1fe63fb47296605f69. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager#57507119] with leader session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Failed to submit job 099acb25fa34be1fe63fb47296605f69 (RMatGraph (s20e16d) ⇨ GraphMetrics ⇨ Hash [integer])
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:492)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:456)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:444)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.graph.Runner.execute(Runner.java:452)
at org.apache.flink.graph.Runner.main(Runner.java:507)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:525)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:417)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:396)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:802)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:282)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1054)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1101)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1098)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1098)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Failed to submit job 099acb25fa34be1fe63fb47296605f69 (RMatGraph (s20e16d) ⇨ GraphMetrics ⇨ Hash [integer])
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1325)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:447)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:38)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:122)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.graph.generator.random.BlockInfo
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:115)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:73)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1859)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1745)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1710)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1550)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:341)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:437)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:424)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:412)
at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:58)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1253)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Did you move the flink-gelly jar from /opt to /lib?

Comment: yup.. both flink-gelly-scala_2.11-1.4.2.jar and flink-gelly_2.11-1.4.2.jar have been moved to flink-1.4.2//lib prior to this happened

Comment: I retry everything with a clean download and run. Now the problem disappear. I can run the examples successfully. But I could no longer reproduce the error... 
BTW, a different error is generated if I remove the above 2 jar files...

Answer (score 0):

This particular error shows up because when you have copied the jar files to the `lib/` folder, but didn't stop and start the flink cluster against after doing the copy (i.e. you had the cluster running before you performed the copy).

If you stop and start the cluster using `./bin/stop-cluster.sh` and `./bin/start-cluster.sh` after copying the jar files to the lib folder as mentioned on this [page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/libs/gelly/#running-gelly-examples) the problem gets fixed.

Also that's probably why you didn't get the error with new installation because you copied the jar files to the lib folder before starting the flink cluster.